# What is wrong with this sql syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Hai guys,

I got the error `Cannot call methods on nvarchar.` when i executed the below sql query

```
select User.[User_Id],User.[User_Name],User.Email_Id,User.Password,Role.Role_Id,Role.Role_Name,Role.Role_Description 
 From [User] inner join [Role] on User.Role_Id=Role.Role_Id
```

what is wrong in the above query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to delimit `user` as `[user]`. I believe it is a reserved keyword.